# HDMI color correction using Arduino or other device. Is this possible?

Tags: arduino, switches, raspberry-pi, hdmi

I have a laptop display that does not come with color correction software available. I'm currently using it as a monitor to play some PS4 games on it but there are some problems with colors. I correctly set color range to Full RGB but I still need some more contrast. As there's no way to change such settings on the display I figured out that I could build an electronic device that would work as a pass-through. Console output would come in one way, contrast and colors would be corrected and then passed to the monitor. Im worried about latency though.

Is that kind of device possible to build on Arduino? Maybe some other platform? Or maybe there's a already working product of that kind on the internet (I couldn't find it myself).

Regards

Comment: Sounds like you need more research. Product suggestions are off topic here too. Arduino can't process HDMI video either.

Comment: Sorry. Any idea how I could achieve desired effect without Arduino?

Comment: An arduino is far, far too slow to do any sort of HDMI processing.

Answer (score 1):

Is the display actually capable of more contrast? There's a maximum black/white contrast ratio which is printed in the spec somewhere.

If you feed it full HDMI black/white signals (000000/FFFFFF) and that's still not enough, then no amount of input changes is going to be able to increase the contrast.

Interception is definitely not possible on either the Arduino or the Pi. Neither is fast enough. It may be possible with FPGA boards, but that's not a simple project.

An additional problem is [HDCP](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/PS4-HDCP-Information?language=en_US). The signal is usually encrypted to prevent you recording DVDs.

Comment: Yes it's capable of displaying beautiful colors. I used it on Windows and it looked great. It's high-quality display.

HDCP is not a problem. I can disable it on PS4.

Any idea how I achieve desired effect?

Comment: HDMI signal goes through that chip to laptop display - http://web.archive.org/web/20180115164704/https://www.st.com/en/display-controllers/stdp6038.html 

Unfortunately it's embedded on laptop motherboard. Maybe there's a way to modify SPI flash and correct colors from there?

Comment: It *could* be achieved by running it through some sort of FPGA board, or maybe an existing video processor, but this sounds complicated and expensive compared to just persuading the PS4 to output the right thing.

Comment: Wish there was some kind of color corrector on PS4 but there's none. Console just tells me to adjust colors using display settings which I obviously don't have. That's why I'm looking for some other solution.

Comment: Frankly, buy a better monitor that has the settings you need.

Comment: The real problem is that nobody produces laptops with HDMI IN ports any more and I'm using my laptop as a display for consoles, set top boxes etc without need to buy external monitor. Otherwise I would have to carry display around with the laptop.

Comment: Why? If you're only using the laptop as a monitor just carry the monitor around instead.

Comment: Hmm.. given https://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2017/03/16/my-ps4-pros-color-has-been-terrible-and-faded-for-months-and-i-finally-fixed-it/?sh=160ee5e46b74 have you tried setting it between to "limited" instead of "full"? I doubt the laptop is HDR

Comment: I'm not. I'm working on it too.

Comment: Yes I've investigated that before. I can't change anything in that option and it stays on "Off". If I try to change it to Auto, the second available option, it says TV doesn't support HDR which is true because this is LVDS display from 2013 when HDR didn't even exist in consoles ;)

Comment: The "limited" and "full" settings don't necessarily work unless the display EDID says it supports it. And if the support is not advertized in the EDID then it does not support it. If you have the EDID data it can be verified.

Comment: On PS4 you can force these settings in case EDID does not contain correct values as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Install OBS Studio on your Raspbery PI, add constrast, or color filters, and out as stream on HDMI. As input you can use HDMI to USB convertor (8$).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcE61dMeo50

Comment: Sure, but it likely does not have anywhere near suitable latency for the application.

Comment: You can buy like XINTEKVIDEO HD-900M color corectors  https://3dhdgear.com/products/xintekvideo-hd-900m-hd-color-corrector-with-12-memory-presets

Comment: Hello. Many thanks for the reply, and sorry for my late reply. I was thinking about this, but latency would be too much, BUT the problem resolved itself with new generation consoles. Both Xbox Series X and PS5 displays correct color through HDMI In without need to correct anything like it was on PS4. PS5 did it right from start (they changed something with system) and Xbox started showing correct colors with system update later so now everything is great! I would gladly give you all an upvote, but I can't because my account is too low rep.

Comment: I have 2 camera what have different color. White Balance don't help, so I need live color correction